# 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'fillna' when filling NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to fill one missing value with an exact number.
I have a covid data set and in Honk Kong there are some columns which have missing values, however I just **one** NaN value to be filled.

```
df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/owid/covid-19-data/master/public/data/owid-covid-data.csv")

df= df[df['date']=='2020-10-27']
df

df[df.location=='Hong Kong']  

value = 5300

##22286 --> it is the index where HK 

df.loc[22286]['total_cases'] = df.loc[22286]['total_cases'].fillna(value)
```

I get the following error:

> AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'fillna'**

Then I tried to convert the value into float:

```
value= float(value)
```

However I get the following message :

> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
>
> See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
> """Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.**

Comment: ```  df[df.location=='Hong Kong']['total_cases']= 5300.0 ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `at` here:

```
df.at[22286, 'total_cases'] = value
print(df.loc[22286]['total_cases'])

5300.0
```

Comment: What about using instead of the index number, can I try by filtering by location?
For example: 
df[df.location=='Hong Kong']['total_cases']= value

Comment: yes it helped :) however I this one :  df[df.location=='Hong Kong']['total_cases']= value . Does not work , may i know why?

Comment: Try to use `loc` instead

Comment: df.loc[df.location='Hong Kong','total_cases']= value --> now it works

Answer (score 2):

`fillna()` is an array function that is mapping the items,
you accessing a single value and not a numpy/pandas array...:

instead do

```
df.loc[22286,'total_cases'] = value
```

Comment: Thanks! in this case would be:
value = 5300.00            df.loc[22286,'total_cases'] = value

Comment: the other answer seems more efficient then my answer...

Comment: note that this is because is a single value, but for many values `loc[]` would work...

Answer (score -1):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

df.loc[17,'Calories']=679

print(df.to_string())
```